# What does "in the middle of the/a pack" mean?

Tags: expressions

Does this expression mean something like "in the middle of some score list", or "average level"?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=define+middle+of+pack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means '*average*', not outstanding by any quality.

> - American 15-year-olds are [middle of the pack](http://articles.baltimoresun.com/2001-12-09/news/0112080169_1_science-and-math-american-students-older-students) in reading, survey shows
> - THE FIRST major international study of reading in a decade shows that American 15-year-olds are about as proficient at reading as they are at mathematics and science. They're adequate but not very good - *the definition of mediocre.*

Source: http://articles.baltimoresun.com

Note: What does MOTP stand for?
  [MOTP](http://www.acronymfinder.com/Middle-of-the-Pack-(MOTP).html) stands for Middle of the Pack

> - This definition appears very rarely and is found in the following Acronym Finder categories: Slang/chat, popular culture

Source: www.acronymfinder.com

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it means not outstanding but not failing.

For example, I will reference cleveland.com site (no offence intended).

> U.S. students in the middle of the pack on financial smarts

Means that US students are not awful at understanding the value of money, but not brilliant. Of the countries / places surveyed, they came about the middle.

As far as I know, there is no technical definition, however I would have thought that for it to be correct, it would be between the [Upper and Lower Quartiles (Q<sub>1</sub> and Q<sub>3</sub>)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartile).

[Article from cleveland.com](http://www.cleveland.com/consumeraffairs/index.ssf/2014/07/us_students_in_the_middle_of_t.html)